# Robotium wait until loading date is finished

Tags: android, testing, robotium

How can i wait until something is done Loading. I need to wait until the application has downloaded about 10MB of data. Since i have implemented the loading into the Robotium class, i don't have the chance to check the UI for an message if it is done.
The loading time takes sometimes longer, so i can't put like `solo.sleep(10000)`.
What other option do i have?

I tried also `sleep.waitForCondition()` and `sleep.waitForLogMessage`. Didn't work neither.

Comment: As a user of the application, how would you tell the download was complete? does anything change on the ui? do elements appear? dissapear?

Comment: Well, the download is normally happening in a other place and have an progress bar. But for the testing, i need them from the beginning. Because the tests are independent and are executed randomly. So i need the data for adding some Objects from start. Thats why i don't have any indicator on the UI when running Robotium.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives:

Loading in the test thread - since Android tests run in a separate thread, you can try downloading in the same thread as the test (it won't throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`). The download will block the test until it is finished (or timed out) and then you can continue the test.

Busy waiting - Create a flag that is set when the loading is finished, and in the test, keep checking this flag until it is set, and then proceed the test.